# A value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double *"

Tags: c++

I'm failing at writing an OpenMP program that has to count an integral using a trapezes method.

The compiler screams at these lines:

```
x = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
y = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
```

> error - a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of
> type "double *"

I'm using Visual Studio 15 and yes, I enabled the OpenMP support in properties.

Here's the part of the program up to the mistake:

```cpp
#define N 4
double start_time, end_time, time;
float f(float x)
{
    return(pow(x, 3));
}
void main() {
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    int i, n;  double *x, *y;
    double x0, xn, h, so, ans;
    x0 = 0;
    xn = 2;
    h = 0.1;
    n = (xn - x0) / h;
    if (n % 2 == 1)
    {
        n = n + 1;
    }
    x = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    y = calloc(n, sizeof(double));
```

Comment: That's C, you're expected to use x = new double[n]; in a C++ program.  If it really, really need to be zero-initialized (does it?) then you need a cast.  And fret a bit that binary zeros also means 0.0.  Well, don't fret too much about that, C++ compilers do tend to like IEEE 754-2008

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) may be a better fit here. It will automatically manage the memory for you. If you find yourself needing the array inside the `vector`, you can get it with the `data` method.

Comment: Note: In C++ your `main` should be `int main()` (not `void`).

Answer (score 4):

The error message is clear and the resolution is straightforward. You need to *explicitly cast* the return value of `calloc` in C++ (unlike in C). That is, if you really need to use such "C-based" routines in C++ ...

```cpp
    x = static_cast<double*>(calloc(n, sizeof(double)));
    y = static_cast<double*>(calloc(n, sizeof(double)));
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `static_cast`?

Comment: @Kevin Yes! (I was a bit carried away).

Comment: Is there any chance of doing the same in plain C without static_cast?

Comment: @coderodde In C, you don't need the cast: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)

Comment: @AdrianMole I meant copying all the bits in a void pointer to a variable of type double. Not double * a = void*